# CakePHP - Reuse custom Libs

Tags: git, class, cakephp

I'm working on multiple CakePHP projects. I've written some Classes and placed them in app/Lib. The classes are being used on multiple projects and provide the same functionality between them.

Every time I want to update these Classes, I need to do for all of my projects. What I want to do is to update the Lib once and then these changes should take effect in other projects too.

How do you think I can achieve this? One way that comes to my mind would be to have a git repo, commit changes to it and then pull from it every time there's a change ... any other ideas?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Its really confusing.... Is your all projects are interrelated to each other.... If they are independent, you have to change all individual files... Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You should read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html
Plugins are the way to go

See [Utils](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils), [Tools](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools) for example.

They can be included using git submodule or better yet composer. The latter is the de facto standard these days for including other plugins. See [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/03/30/using-composer/) and linked references on details.